# Why can't I publish my ASP.Net project from VS2015 to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I can't enter a webapp name when I create a new project, as well as after creating the project. I still cant publish to Azure because of the same reason.

I've tried the following available tutorials online but still the same. Both of my VS and Azure's accounts are the same.

This is how it looks like.

[image: Cant enter webapp name when creating a new project]

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a workaround instead. Create the webapp in Azure portal. Then publish it again and choose the existing webapp.